# How to remove C# null reference warning CS8604

Tags: c#

I am getting the compiler warning CS8604 that cachedData is possibly null. I am not sure how to eliminate this warning despite checking cachedData for null. Help please.

```
string cacheKey = "Test1";
RedisValue cachedData = await cache.StringGetAsync(cacheKey);

if (cachedData.HasValue && !cachedData.IsNullOrEmpty)
{
    IList<Model1>? result = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Model1>>(cachedData);

    if (result != null)
    {
        data = result;
        return data;
    }
}

data = await repo.GetModel1();

await cache.StringSetAsync(cacheKey, 
                           JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), 
                           TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            
return data
```

Comment: **Exactly** which line is the warning being given on?

Comment: `RedisValue cachedData = await cache.StringGetAsync(cacheKey);` should be `RedisValue? cachedData = await cache.StringGetAsync(cacheKey).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to deserialize to `IList<T>` - even though Newtonsoft.Json is smart about it, you should be in the habit of only deserializing to defined _concrete types_.

Comment: As `repo.GetModel1()` returns an awaitable, it should be named `repo.GetModelAsync` and you'll probably want to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to that too. Also consider supporting `CancellationToken`.

Comment: @Dai the line with the warning is IList<MedicineSubSpecialty>? result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MedicineSubSpecialty>>(cachedData); Specifically, the compiler said cachedData is possibly null.

Comment: What is `StringGetAsync` going to do if it can't find an entry with a matching `cacheKey`?

Comment: @gunr2171 I just tested it - it returned an empty cachedData, which makes HasValue = false and IsNullEmpty = true. RedisValue is a non-null type.

Comment: If you are 100.00% confident that cachedData is not null, you can use the ! operator on the variable in the Deserialize call, as in `cachedData!`.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram That is the answer I was looking for. If you post it I will mark it as the answer. A side note, using .ConfigureAwait(false) gave me a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 100.00% confident that `cachedData` is not null, you can use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `!` on the variable in the Deserialize call, as in `cachedData!`. This is useful when the compiler does not otherwise know that the variable is non-null.